# Docker and Neo4J

Tags: docker, neo4j, dockerfile

I'm trying to get a Neo4J database up and running in a docker container.
Currently i have it running by using the command:

```
docker run -d -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 neo4j
```

.. and it's working fine.

I want to put it in a Dockerfile so i can do some server configuration, but when i use the Dockerfile, it does not expose the ports that i have set it to expose unless i explicitly expose them when i do "docker run":

```
FROM neo4j
ENV NEO4J_AUTH neo4j/password
EXPOSE 7474:7474
EXPOSE 7687:7687
```

Did i misunderstand something, or shouldn't the ports be exposed automatically with this configuration?

Answer (score 3):

> The EXPOSE instruction informs Docker that the container listens on
>   the specified network ports at runtime. EXPOSE does not make the ports
>   of the container accessible to the host. To do that, you must use
>   either the -p flag to publish a range of ports or the -P flag to
>   publish all of the exposed ports. You can expose one port number and
>   publish it externally under another number.
>
> To set up port redirection on the host system, see using the -P flag.
>   The Docker network feature supports creating networks without the need
>   to expose ports within the network, for detailed information see the
>   overview of this feature).

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: Ah okay. So EXPOSE is not meant for publishing ports. I see that it is not even possible through dockerfiles. I will use docker-compose in stead.